# Eclipse code selection highilghting is white & not transparent

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse suddenly starting highlighting selections in my pom.xml in a non-transparent white background.  Java files still have a transparent blue background.  What setting do I need to change to get the XML files back to blue transparent? Note, I did not make any setting changes.  It just happened.

See below for details.  The white section is highlighted.

[image]

Comment: The _Selection background color_ can be set in the preferences _General > Editors > Text Editors_ in the section _Appearance color options_ at the bottom. If this does not help, please tell the exact version of Eclipse and of m2e and your OS.

Comment: @howlger I had the same issue. It helped to change to another color and back again. Thanks.